# What writing utensils would work for concrete walls?

Tags: material-selection

My boyfriend has concrete walls surrounding his at home office. He has expressed interest in using the walls as "story boarding" space for future mobile applications. **I'm curious as to what writing utensil would be the very best option for clarity of penmanship on a concrete wall.** Being able to be washed off after a period of time would be a bonus too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When dealing with a concrete surface, the first consideration is the smoothness of the surface. If that is acceptable, and of reasonably decent flatness, your options expand nicely. If it's a coarse surface with lots of pits, cracks and other irregularities, chalk may be the only answer. It's messy and washable, though.

If the surface can be painted, consider to use a dry-erase paint product. I found many with a quick search:

[Benjamin Moore Dry Erase Paint](https://www.benjaminmoore.com/en-us/notable-dry-erase-paint)

Such products will enable one to use standard office-type dry-erase markers of multiple colors and tip sizes, with easy dry-erase erasers used to remove the work.

Depending on the scope of the use (area of walls to be painted), the biggest disadvantage I see is that the room would be very white.

Comment: they also sell chalkboard paint, which is slightly more forgiving of rough surfaces.

Comment: I have a can of the stuff. Even if not used for intended labeling, it's good quality paint, fairly durable, although matte finish, of course.